# Python: Передача статического метода в конструктор другого класса

Tags: python, ооп, классы, static, инициализация

У меня есть три класса:

1. Класс, представляющий пункт меню:

```
class MenuItem:
    def __init__(self, title, function):
        self.title = title
        self.function = function

    def execute(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.function(*args, **kwargs)
```

2. Класс, представляющий меню:

```
class Menu:
    def __init__(self, title, items):
        self.items = items
        self.title = title
```

3. Статический класс, представляющий интерфейс:

```
class GameUI:
    mainmenu = Menu("", [
        MenuItem("1. Start the game", None),
        MenuItem("2. Settings", None),
        MenuItem("3. Exit", GameUI._exit)
    ])

    @classmethod
    def _exit(cls):
        pass
```

Когда я пытаюсь проинициализировать переменную `mainmenu` в классе `GameUI`, то получаю ошибку о том, что `имя GameUI не определено`, если же передавать функцию `_exit` без указания класса, то при вызове функции приходится передавать и класс: `GameUI.gamemenu.items[2].execute(GameUI)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой вариант - вынести инициализацию за пределы класса.
Более сложный вариант - метакласс.

```
    # вариант 1
class GameUI1:

    @classmethod
    def _exit(cls):
        print('GameUI1 exit')


GameUI1.mainmenu = Menu("", [
    MenuItem("1. Start the game", None),
    MenuItem("2. Settings", None),
    MenuItem("3. Exit", GameUI1._exit)
])

#вариант 2
class GameUIMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        menu_cls = super(GameUIMeta, cls).__new__(cls,*args,**kwargs)
        menu_cls.mainmenu = Menu("", [
            MenuItem("1. Start the game", None),
            MenuItem("2. Settings", None),
            MenuItem("3. Exit", menu_cls._exit)
        ])
        return menu_cls


class GameUI2(metaclass=GameUIMeta):
    @classmethod
    def _exit(cls):
        print('GameUI2 exit')


gu1 = GameUI1()
gu2 = GameUI2()

gu1.mainmenu.items[2].execute()
gu2.mainmenu.items[2].execute()
```

Answer (score 1):

Питон интерпретирует последовательно в каких-то случаях. Поэтому тут сначала нужно определить функцию, а потом на неё ссылаться. Так уже не ругается:

```
class GameUI:
    @classmethod
    def _exit(cls):
        pass 

    mainmenu = Menu("", [
        MenuItem("1. Start the game", None),
        MenuItem("2. Settings", None),
        MenuItem("3. Exit", GameUI._exit)
    ])
```

Answer (score 1):

Только python 3.x.
Можно несколько иначе реализовать метод `__get__` для объекта свойства

```
class classproperty: # создали свойство (тн дескриптор не данных)

    def __init__(self, fget):
        self.fget = fget

    def __get__(self, instance, objtype):
        return self.fget(objtype) # обычно передаётся instance вместо objtype

class GameUI:
    mainmenu: Menu

    @classmethod
    def _exit(cls):
        pass

    @classproperty
    def mainmenu(cls): # первое обращение к свойству инициализирует объект
        print('call parent class')
        setattr(cls, 'mainmenu', Menu("", [MenuItem("1. Start the game", None),
                                           MenuItem("2. Settings", None),
                                           MenuItem("3. Exit", cls._exit)]))
        return cls.mainmenu # все последующие обращения будут возвращать атрибут самого класса
```